When using a Word template, the Enter Key re-populates bookmarks rather than moving to the next line
I created a Word template that uses a form (named SCRINFO) to collect information. This information populates several bookmarks in the first page header of the document and in the header of all other pages.
Starting off I open Word, click the New button, and select the template. The data collection form pops up, I enter the information, and click the form's Submit button. The button's code (shown below) populates the bookmarks in the header and automatically saves the document with a filename based on the information entered in the form. Here's a view of the form that collects the information:
Input form
The Submit button hides the form and the Word document is available for further editing:
Word document after information form closes
I click below the word "Issue" and type some information. When I press the Enter Key, rather than moving my cursor to the next line, the information from the form's fields are once again added to the bookmarks in the header.
Form's information added to bookmarks again
Pressing the Enter key repeatedly just keeps adding the same information to the bookmarks:
After repeatedly pressing the Enter key
I set this template up using information found online but I'm not very familiar with Word at all. It seems like the focus is somehow on the form's Submit button and pressing it just runs the code again, and again.
Any help and/or pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated!!
Thanks!
Private Sub cmdDone_Click()
Dim VersionPage1 As Range
Set VersionPage1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("VersionPage1").Range
VersionPage1.Text = Me.txtVersion.Value

Dim SCRNumberPage1 As Range
Set SCRNumberPage1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SCRNumberPage1").Range
SCRNumberPage1.Text = Me.txtSCRNumber.Value

Dim SCRTitle As Range
Set SCRTitle = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SCRTitle").Range
SCRTitle.Text = Me.txtSCRTitle.Value

Dim Version As Range
Set Version = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Version").Range
Version.Text = Me.txtVersion.Value

Dim SCRNumber As Range
Set SCRNumber = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SCRNumber").Range
SCRNumber.Text = Me.txtSCRNumber.Value

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=Me.txtVersion.Value & " SCR-" & Me.txtSCRNumber.Value & " " & Me.txtSCRTitle.Value & ".docx"

Me.Repaint
SCRINFO.Hide
End Sub

The code in ThisDocument is:
Private Sub Document_New()
Dim Author As Range
Set Author = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Author").Range
Author.Text = Environ("USERNAME")

Dim AuthorPage1 As Range
Set AuthorPage1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AuthorPage1").Range
AuthorPage1.Text = Environ("USERNAME")
SCRINFO.Show

End Sub


All your code does is hide the form. It doesn’t unload it. The last line of that routine should be: Unload SCRINFO
